# +[VKSdk initializeWithAppId:]: unrecognized selector sent to class, but class and method exist

Tags: ios, iphone, exception, ios-simulator, vk-sdk

I have a problem with use library via CocoaPods - VKSDK.

My code for initialize SDK:

```
self.vkSdk = [VKSdk initializeWithAppId:VK_APPLICATION_IDENTIFIER];
```

And this code throws exception:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[VKSdk initializeWithAppId:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x100574578
```

But! The class is exist and function too.

Code from library:

```
+ (instancetype)initializeWithAppId:(NSString *)appId {
    return [VKSdk initializeWithAppId:appId apiVersion:VK_SDK_API_VERSION];
}
```

**Very interesting:** This code not working only on device (iPhone 6), in simulator - all OK.

Can XCode have any flags for compile in simulator and device?